# Using JobStoreCMT in Quartz - preventing automatic commit

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use a JDBC Job Store in Quartz with the following code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().plusHours(2);

JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(identifier, "group", TestJob.class);
SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(identifier, dt.toDate());

trigger.setJobName(identifier);
trigger.setJobGroup("group");

quartzScheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
```

And am configuring the scheduler as follows:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
<property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
<property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="schedulerDataSource" />
<property name="nonTransactionalDataSource" ref="nonTXdataSource" />
<property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
        <!--Job Store -->
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">
            org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
        </prop>

        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">
            org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
        </prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
```

The `schedulerDataSource` is a standard JNDI data source, the `nonTXdataSource` is configured via a simple `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` I have specified the job store class to be: o`rg.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT` and was hoping that the code:

```
quartzScheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
```

would not commit the job to the database when the each method is called. Basically when I call addJob the job is immediately saved to the database, the scheduleJob method causes the trigger information to be immediately saved in the database as well, but this tends to happen over two separate transactions already.

There is a fair bit of subsequent logic in the code that needs to be committed to the database together with the scheduled jobs in one transactions, however no matter what I try the jobs are committed by the scheduler to the database as soon as they methods are called. I tried in various environments Testing/Tomcat/Glassfish and various configurations of data sources but to no avail.

Can somebody point me into the direction of where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having thought this over a bit, now i believe you can achieve this providing your own wrapping `DataSource` but you *should not do this*. I think Quartz maintains some internal state in memory that must be in sync with the database (or at least it can do so). If you rollback a transaction or otherwise modify database state not notifying Quartz about this fact, it may not work as expected.

On the other hand you can use Quartz's pausing of the jobs to achieve similar effect: you simply create new job and pause it before adding any triggers. Then, you resume it only after you commit your transaction.

---------------------- my original answer ----------------------

I think, but I'm not sure, not tried this, that you can try the following:

You need a transaction around a code that uses `DataSource.getConnection` internally. To achieve that you have to use data source that'd be aware of global transaction state. I suppose that JBoss application server gives you just that (even with plain data source).

JBoss comes with a transaction manager (Arjuna) and data sources wrappers (JBoss app server internal) that are at least aware of global transaction state.

Other options include Atomikos and a XA data source, but i have less experience here.

Edit: if Quartz uses explicit `COMMIT` or `setAutocommit(true)` internally, both my suggestions would not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you set datasource on SchedulerFactoryBean, spring uses below class as JobStore ( extension to Quartz's JobStoreCMT )

[LocalDataSourceJobStore](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/LocalDataSourceJobStore.html)
This supports both transactional and non-transactional DataSource access.

Please try following

1. Remove property org.quartz.jobStore.class [Edit : Its ignored ,anyways]
2. Make sure the method which does addJob / ScheduleJob is in spring managed transaction.

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back, was away for a few days. The problem is that I am not actually wrapping the method in a Spring managed transaction, I am using Cayenne for an ORM which takes care of the transaction management for me in its ObjectContext. I am starting to think that it may not be possible to achieve what I am trying to do unless I wrap the method in a managed transaction. Will do some more research on this today!

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/CAY/spring-integrationexamples.html                                            This contains spring - Cayenne integration example, You need to code a CayenneTemplate <for Spring's JdbcTemplate>. Let me know, If you need more help on this.You have interesting job to do ...

Comment: I've considered that already but as the page says "consider whether it is worth adding another layer of indirection to your application". It seems like a fair bit of work for a simple task, but perhaps it's the only way to go.